# Unable to use node.js web session data in cordova mobile application

Tags: node.js, cordova, session, phonegap

We have developed a website in normal html and js in the frontend and node.js in the backend.
I have used sessions data to get somethings done such as welcome email or mobile otp verification after the successful registration.

Now we are developing a cordova app with same backend api's and the actual problem comes here.I am unable to access my sessions data i.e.. req.session.user is null which I have updated after the successfull registration.
Can someone please suggest what is the solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

In order to work session properly, you need to pass the sessionId in every request on the website this ID will set in a cookie and automatically send in every request.

When comes on to mobile you can achieve the session with the following approach.

1)When a user successfully logged in issue a token and store that token in your Cordova app (usually in local storage).

2)For every request pass this token along and check whether the token exists or not.

Note: You can attach the token in the authorization header